# iPhone 6 iCloud Backup is super large

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup

I recently jumped from an iPhone 4s running 8.1.2 to an iPhone 6+ and suddenly there is no more room for iCloud backups. When I go into "manage storage" I can see my old phone at 2.6GB and my iPad at 1.2GB.

My new phone was originally "restored" from my old phone, but my new phone tells me my next backup is going to be 4.2GB. This means I don't have room for one phone and one iPad in iCloud when I used to have room for just that.

Why is the backup suddenly so much larger, and what can I do about it? (My wife is also having the same issue although she went from 4s to a plain 6.)

Comment: If your old phone is successfully restored you can get rid of that backup and save space, it will never go away on it's own.  Not sure why the new phone is so much larger tho, do you have the same backup options turned on?

Comment: Thank you @Tyson ... I do know the old one won't go away on its own. But until I can be reasonably assured the new one will back up (i.e. iPhone + iPad < 5 GB), I'm not going to delete it. I need an answer to the size problem first.

Comment: If you do not want to free up the necessary space then you'll need to purchase additional storage.  Have a look at: [iCloud storage pricing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201238)

Comment: Back it up to iTunes first, using encryption, which also saves passwords & login credentials. Then you're free to experiment.

Comment: It's not a matter of being "unwilling" to free up the space. It's a matter of I don't know what's taking up the space. Start with a phone, back it up, restore to a different phone, and suddenly the space requirements are 50% larger? Makes no sense.